# open another aspx page on submitting if all validation verified

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have this asp page with some regex and validation, I want when clicking on the button if all validation is verified to open another page on click, how can I do that asp or JavaScript? and if some validation are not verified, and the client clicked on the button, only show the error message and stays on the same page

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    </head>
        <a id="a1" runat="server" href="result.aspx"></a>
    <body dir="rtl" align="center" runat="server">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div class=" nan">
                <p class="bab"> Add a product </p>
                <asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" ShowMessageBox="true" ShowSummary="false" />
                
                <label for="product_Name" runat="server"> productName</label> <br/>
    
                <asp:TextBox id="product_Name"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="reqName"  ControlToValidate="product_Name" ErrorMessage=" يرجى ادخال اسم المنتج" Display="None" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
               <br/>
                <label for="productNumber" runat="server">رقم المنتج  :</label><br/>
                <asp:TextBox  id="productNumber" name="productNumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqNumber" runat="server" ErrorMessage="الرجاء ادخال الرقم" ControlToValidate="productNumber"  Display="None"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <br/>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"   runat="server" ErrorMessage="رقم المنتج  : الرجاء ادخال رقم من 10 خانات اول 3 من الاحرف والباقي ارقام" ValidationExpression="/^[A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{7}$/" ControlToValidate="productNumber"  Display="None" ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                <br/>
    
                <p>اختر بلد التصنيع  :
                                
                <label for="product_Name" runat="server">
                    <select id="waw" name ="select list" runat="server" >
    
                    <option value="Afganistan" >*****</option>
                    <option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
                    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                </select></label><br/>
                    </p>
                    
    
                <label for="Type" runat="server"> نوع المنتج :</label><br/>
                <asp:TextBox id="Type" name="Type" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server"   Display="None" ErrorMessage="نوع المنتج : الرجاء ادخال محارف او ارقام فقط" ValidationExpression="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/" ControlToValidate="Type"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                <br/>
    
                <label for="year " runat="server">سنة التصنيع  :</label><br/>
                <asp:TextBox id="year" name="year" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server"  Display="None"  ErrorMessage="سنة التصنيع : الرجاء ادخال رقم موجب من 4 خانات" ValidationExpression="/^[0-9]{4}$/" ControlToValidate="year"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                <br/>
                    <label for="Price" runat="server">السعر :</label><br/>
                <asp:TextBox id="Price" name="Price" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="السعر: الرجاء ادخال رقم بين 0 الى 10000"  Display="None"  MaximumValue="100000" MinimumValue="0" ControlToValidate="Price"></asp:RangeValidator>
                <br/>
            </div>
               <asp:Button ID="myBtn" runat ="server" Text ="add new product"/>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Some tags need to be changed. It is not related to asp.net core

Comment: ASP.NET MVC 3 does not use WebForms either (while MVC3 can use `.aspx` as views, but you cannot use Controls like `<asp:TextBox>`).

Comment: Also, _why are you using WebForms unironically in 2021_?